# Change the order of random sentences

Tags: php

I have a long text (3600 sentences) and I want to change the order of random sentences. There are some simple PHP script that can change the order of sentences?

Comment: Put the sentences in an array and use `shuffle` to randomize the array.

Comment: Please show what you tried, we're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: Do all your sentences end with '.' or can they also end with '?' or '!' ?

Comment: I just realized "..." and "?!" are also grammatically correct ways to end sentences.... And let's not even talk about "!!!11!!1!!" and these...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I constructed a solution which solves the problem for sentences ending with ".", "!" or "?". I noticed that it is not a good idea to include the very last part of the sentences array in the shuffling, because the last part is never supposed to end with the particular character we're splitting on:

"Hi.| Hello.| "

I hope you get the idea. So I shuffle all the elements except the last. And I do the work separately for ".", "?", and "!".

You should know that "...", "?!", "!!!11!!1!!" will cause big trouble. :):)

```
<?php
function randomizeOrderOnDelimiter($glue,$sentences){

    $sentencesArray = explode($glue, $sentences);

    // Get out the items to shuffle: all but the last.
    $work = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($sentencesArray)-1; $i++) {
        $work[$i] = $sentencesArray[$i];
    }

    shuffle($work);  // shuffle them

    // And put them back.
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($sentencesArray)-1; $i++) {
        $sentencesArray[$i] = $work[$i];
    }

    $sentences = implode($glue, $sentencesArray);
    return $sentences;
}

$sentences = 'Hello, this is one sentence. This is a second. THis is a third. This is a forth. This is a fifth. Sixth is imperative! Is seventh a question? Eighth is imperative! Is ninth also a question? Tenth.';
$sentences = randomizeOrderOnDelimiter('.', $sentences);
$sentences = randomizeOrderOnDelimiter('?', $sentences);
$sentences = randomizeOrderOnDelimiter('!', $sentences);
var_dump($sentences);

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish it like this. Explode a string on the end of a sentence e.g full stop. Shuffle the array using the `shuffle` function. Then implode the string, adding the full stops back.

The output will be something like:

`Hello, this is one sentence. This is a fifth. This is a forth. This is a second.. THis is a third`

```
$sentences = 'Hello, this is one sentence. This is a second. THis is a third. This is a forth. This is a fifth.';

$sentencesArray = explode('.', $sentences);
array_filter($sentencesArray);
shuffle($sentencesArray);

$sentences = implode('.', $sentencesArray);


var_dump($sentences);
```

Comment: It works! You're a genius, I love you! :) Is it possible to implement "?" and "!"? I'm not a programmer. Simply insert symbols here - ('.''?''!', $sentences)? Thank you!